# Why can't my Python program find the jq module?

Tags: python, python-3.4, jq

I try to use the Python jq module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Python 3.4

#--------------------------
import datetime
import sys
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import time
from jq import jq
```

When I run it on the command line:

```
# ./daemon.py
```

it says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./daemon.py", line 10, in <module>
    from jq import jq
ImportError: No module named 'jq'
```

List of installed python packages:

```
# pip search jq
```

shows this:

```
...
jq (0.1.6)         - jq is a lightweight and flexible JSON processor.
...
```

So why can't my program import the jq module?

Comment: You probably installed it for Python 2. If that's true, try `pip3 install jq`.

Comment: What does `pip -V` return? Does interpreter path match interpreter used by your script?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski

`pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip search` searches through *available* packages. To list *installed* packages, use `pip list`.

Try installing the `jq` module with `pip install jq`.